# Why does the variable return 0 always?

Tags: android, sqlite, variables

I am trying to retrieve the count from a Sqlite database. But the variable number is always returning zero even if I adda values in the database. can anyone tell me step by step what am I doing wrong. Here is my code.

```
 public int isUserAvailable(Double latitude,Double longitude)
{
int number = 0;
Cursor c = null;

try
{
    c = db.rawQuery("select latitude,longitude from savedlocation where latitude = ? and longitude = ? ", new String[] {String.valueOf(latitude),String.valueOf(longitude)});

    if(c.getCount() != 0)
        number = c.getCount();

}
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if(c!=null) c.close();
}
return number;
}
```

I think its because I have initialized number=0; so its returning that value. I am not able to access number outside try.

Comment: may be cursor is empty...

Comment: move the cursor to the first row 
     `if(c.moveToFirst())`

Comment: The query didn't return anything or there was an exception. Floating point is inherently inaccurate and you're looking for an exact match. Consider using e.g. integer microdegrees instead.

Comment: @Raghunandan Doesn't matter, he's not accessing cursor data, just the count.

Answer (score 0):

`{String.valueOf(latitude),String.valueOf(longitude)}` may be the problem

it doesnt happen EVERY time, but sometimes String.valueOf returns an unexpected value

something like `u - s - e - r - a - r - r - y`

try `latitude+""` , `longitude+""` to convert them to string.

cursor.moveToFirst should not affect cursor.getCount()

```
 public int isUserAvailable(Double latitude,Double longitude)
{
int number = 0;
Cursor c = null;

try
{
    c = db.rawQuery("select latitude,longitude from savedlocation where latitude = ? and longitude = ? ", new String[] {latitude+"",longitude+""});

    if(c.getCount() != 0)
        number = c.getCount();

}
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if(c!=null) c.close();
}
return number;
}
```

On a side note, if you want to just get the number of rows that match a query try this:

```
public int isUserAvailable(Double latitude,Double longitude)
{
int number = 0;
Cursor c = null;

try
{
    c = db.rawQuery("select count(*) from savedlocation where latitude = ? and longitude = ? ", new String[] {latitude+"",longitude+""});

    if(c.moveToFirst())
        number = c.getInt(0);

}
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if(c!=null) c.close();
}
return number;
}
```

Comment: I think its because I have initialized number=0; so its returning that value. I am not able to access number outside try.